# Неверные значения из doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Использую symfony 1.4, есть метод в модели:

```
public static function getByType($type_id) {
        $query = Doctrine::getTable('TypeEvent')->createQuery()
                ->select('*')->where('type_id=?');
        return $query->fetchArray(array($type_id));
}
```

Структура таблички:

```
TypeEvent:
  columns:
    type_id: integer
    event_type: integer
    event_to:
      type: boolean
      default: 0
    created_at: timestamp
```

Проблема в том что у меня данные с пометкой `event_to` равной 2, а выводятся с пометкой `event_to` равной 1. Все значения верны, кроме этого.